# Как избавиться от ошибки ORA-00704 и желательно навсегда?

Tags: oracle

Ну так вот. У меня стоит Oracle XE 11gR1. Конечно она не поддерживает вообще множественные пути для ORACLE_HOME , и даже создание дополнительной БД на одном пути ORACLE_HOME , однако создать вторую БД в XE всё же реально , что я и пытаюсь сделать. Однако сразу после того как я создал экземпляр БД , его сконфигурировал , создал табличное пространство , а уже потом запустил экземпляр, для завершения создания второй БД я в нём запустил скрипты сначала catalog.sql и catproc.sql в неправильном порядке(надо было сначала catalog.sql , а уже потом catproc.sql) , в результате чего через некоторое время при попытке открыть БД с помощью запроса alter database open; возникла ошибка следующего плана:

```sql
alter database open 
*
error at line 1: 
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced 
ORA-00704: bootstrap process failure 
ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option
```

В блогах говорили , что необходимо обновить релиз и уже потом опять запустить эти два скрипта снова, чтобы выйти из такой ситуации как , например , здесь:

http://sandeepbirineni.blogspot.com.ee/2013/03/ora-00704-bootstrap-process-failure-ora.html

Другого совета я просто не нашёл. Поэтому пришлось пойти по этому пути. На повторном запуске скриптов уже в правильном порядке все объекты словаря данных собрались однако некоторые с ошибками компиляции(например , связанные с регистрами и Java). И спустя некоторое время после принуждённого апгрейда эти ошибки , приведённые выше вернулись. Файл трассировки прилагается (https://vk.com/doc27309941_440899659?hash=daeafd7a... ), хотя мне не понятно точно , что не так поскольку ошибки там происходят после того как БД оповестила об ошибке с bootstrap поэтому и связи не вижу. Вот. Скажите пожалуйста: что мне делать ? Какие способы исправления ошибок здесь подойдут и если возможно по детальнее о них описать. Или если это единственное решение кроме переинсталляции XE с нуля , то стоит ли мне даунгрейдить релиз с помощью catdwgrd.sql , чтобы стереть все последствия неверного генерирования объектов скриптом catupgrd.sql или нужно будет чтото ещё ?